# Symfony2: You have requested a non-existent parameter

Tags: php, symfony, openshift

I have checked similar questions on SO, but they did not solve my issue.

I am deploying a Symfony2 application on Openshift. It works well on my Windows 10 laptop, but I am getting the following [error message](http://symfony2demo-tshikaaa.rhcloud.com/) on Openshift:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Exception\ParameterNotFoundException'
with message 'You have requested a non-existent parameter "database_path".
Did you mean one of these: "database_host", "database_port", "database_name", "database_user"?'
in /var/lib/openshift/55eed4837628e1199f0000bb/app-root/runtime/repo/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/ParameterBag/ParameterBag.php:106 Stack trace: #0 
/var/lib/openshift/55eed4837628e1199f0000bb/app-root/runtime/repo/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/ParameterBag/ParameterBag.php(248):
Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ParameterBag\ParameterBag->get('database_path') #1 [internal function]:
Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ParameterBag\ParameterBag->Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ParameterBag\{closure}(Array) #2
/var/lib/openshift/55eed4837628e1199f0000bb/app-root/runtime/repo/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/ParameterBag/ParameterBag.php in
/var/lib/openshift/55eed4837628e1199f0000bb/app-root/runtime/repo/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/ParameterBag/ParameterBag.php on line 106
```

My `config.yml` is:

```
imports:
    - { resource: parameters.yml }
    - { resource: security.yml }
    - { resource: services.yml }
...

doctrine:
    dbal:
        driver:   pdo_sqlite
        charset:  UTF8
        path:     "%kernel.root_dir%/../%database_path%"
...
```

My `parameters.yml` is:

```
parameters:
    database_driver: pdo_sqlite
    database_host: localhost
    database_port: null
    database_name: demo.db
    database_user: root
    database_password: null
    database_path: /data/demo.db
    ...
```

and my `config_prod.yml` is:

```
imports:
    - { resource: config.yml }
...
```

What am I doing wrong?

**Update**

I have changed my `config.yml` to:

```
path:     "%kernel.root_dir%/../data/demo.db"
```

and the issue is gone, but I don't know why!

Comment: Did you get the exception also in the dev environment? Did you run `cache:clear`?

Comment: I did not have this issue when running `app_dev.php`. I have just ssl logged into my openshift application and ran `php app/console cache:clear --env=prod`. I am getting exactly the same error from the command line...

Comment: Always running composer install, symfony regenerate a new config.yml from config.yml.dist. Disd you have updated your config.yml.dist?  From openshift SSH check if config.yml is okay.
   `$ cat $OPENSHIFT_REPO_DIR/app/config/parameters.yml`

Comment: Mmmm the `cat` command reveals that the parameter was not in my `parameters.yml`. Indeed, I did not update it in `.dist`. Newbie error. @felipsmartins If you create the solution, I'll approve it. Thanks.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

This is a common mistake.

Just like I have commented above:
When running **composer** install, symfony will regenerate a new `parameters.yml` file based on `parameters.yml.dist` (if any).
So it's a good idea always check if `parameters.yml` generated by symfony (on post install event, composer) is okay.

Also:

> Whenever you update the `parameters.yml` file (with configs that
>   should be in the prod server also well), you must update the file
>   `parameters.yml.dist` too.

So the deployment process will be much less painful.